# Google Street View API Image Doesn't Snap to Closest Photographed Location Like Maps Does

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I'm working with the Street View Image API. When I specify a lat/long pair, such as `43.2345,-71.5227` in a query like this:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=640x480&location=43.2345,-71.5227

I get an image that says "Sorry, we have no imagery here". The Google docs for this API specify that "The Google Street View Image API will snap to the panorama photographed closest to this location." It doesn't appear to be doing that.

If I pull up those same coordinates directly by pasting them into Google Maps, then it identifies a location at a slightly different lat/long pair (`43.234727,-71.524926`) that *does* have a street view image:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=640x480&location=43.234727,-71.524926

In other words, it seems that Google Maps does pull up the closest known location but the Street View API does not. Is there a way to force the closest street view location to come up? Or a way to query an API that will give me the best coordinates to use?

Comment: I think you need to have a precise `latitude` and `longitude` for that. But also you can set a bound for not providing the precise coordinates and still can return street view around it.

Comment: I'm definitely not seeing a bound parameter on the Street View Image API. Are you thinking of some other API? Or am I missing it?

Answer (score 0):

Try use StreetViewService. It determine nearby street view panorama or photosphere.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview?hl=en

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#StreetViewLocationRequest

May be this will be useful: "OUTDOOR: Limits Street View searches to outdoor collections. Indoor collections are not included in search results. Note also that the search only returns panoramas where it's possible to determine whether they're indoors or outdoors. For example, PhotoSpheres are not returned because it's unknown whether they are indoors or outdoors.".
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#StreetViewSource

After obtaining and set pano into Street View grab new coordinates and then pass into `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview`